# Error con la Pk de mi clases en .NET Core

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core

buenas tardes comunidad , tengo un problema como mis clases , pasa que me dieron una bd en la cual , las tablas no cuentan con pk ni autoincrementan , y desde el código se tiene que poner el pk y el autoincremental , para poder traer todas las tablas utilize el modelo scaffold , pero ahora al crear un nuevo registro me marca este error de pk , ya puse el pk y autoincremental desde mi clase , ¿cual seria el error?

este es mi repository

```
public string newPersona(Mpersona persona)
        {
            string mensaje = "";
            var validarPer = _condominioContext.Mpersonas;
            Mpersona per = new Mpersona
            {
            
              MpersApePaterno = persona.MpersApeMaterno,
              MpersApeMaterno=persona.MpersApeMaterno,
              MpersNombres=persona.MpersNombres,
              MpersTipoDoc=persona.MpersTipoDoc,
              MpersNumeroDoc=persona.MpersNumeroDoc,
              MpersTelefonoMovil1=persona.MpersTelefonoMovil1,
              MpersTelefonoMovil2=persona.MpersTelefonoMovil2,
              MpersTelefonoFijo=persona.MpersTelefonoFijo,
              MpersCorreo1=persona.MpersCorreo1,
              MpersCorreo2=persona.MpersCorreo2,
              MpersSexo=persona.MpersSexo,
              MpersFechaNacimiento=persona.MpersFechaNacimiento,
              MpersEstado=1,
              MpersNomCompleto=persona.MpersNombres
             };

            if(validarPer.Any(x => x.MpersNumeroDoc.Equals(persona.MpersNumeroDoc)))
            {
                mensaje = "El número de documento ya existe , ingrese otro";
            }
            else
            {
                _condominioContext.Mpersonas.Add(per);
                _condominioContext.SaveChanges();
                mensaje = "La persona fue creada con exito";
            }

            return mensaje;
            
        }
```

este es mi controller

```
  [HttpPost("newPersona")]
        public ActionResult newPersona([FromBody]Mpersona personas)
        {
            IActionResult result = Unauthorized();
            string rpta = _adminService.newPersona(personas);
            try
            {
                if (rpta.Equals(""))
                {
                    result = Ok(new { messaje = rpta, error = false, data = new { per = personas } });
                }
                else
                {
                    result = Ok(new { messaje = rpta, error = true });
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                result = Ok(new { messaje = "Revisar el sistema", error = true });
            }

            return Ok(result);
        }
```

esta es mi clas mpersona

```
namespace Condominios.Models
{
    public partial class Mpersona
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int MpersId { get; set; }
        public string MpersApePaterno { get; set; }
        public string MpersApeMaterno { get; set; }
        public string MpersNombres { get; set; }
        public int MpersTipoDoc { get; set; }
        public string MpersNumeroDoc { get; set; }
        public string MpersTelefonoMovil1 { get; set; }
        public string MpersTelefonoMovil2 { get; set; }
        public string MpersTelefonoFijo { get; set; }
        public string MpersCorreo1 { get; set; }
        public string MpersCorreo2 { get; set; }
        public string MpersSexo { get; set; }
        public DateTime? MpersFechaNacimiento { get; set; }
        public int MpersEstado { get; set; }
        public string MpersNomCompleto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

este es mi tabla en sql

```
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

Comment: Cuál es el error de pk?

Comment: Cual es el codigo que utilizar para incrementar el pk?

Comment: como podría poner el autoincremental desde .net , ya que en la bd no esta definido